# Stop and copy garbage collector in two phases

Tags: garbage-collection, racket

When implementing a stop and copy garbage collector as a pair, I need two memory banks (the old one and a free new one). One memory bank consists of the-cars and the-cdrs. So basicly when I make a new addres, it is a pointer to the-cars and the-cdrs.

When allocating new memory and I see that I don't have enough space, I start a GC. What this one does is:

- switch the memory banks
- move: read car and cdr from the old bank, copy to the new bank and put a pointer in the old bank to the new for later.
- scan: loops over the memory and copies everything from old to new.

Now the question is: Why do I need to scan first and move after. Why can't I do both together?

Comment: What do you mean by the "as a pair" part of the first sentence?

Comment: Note to the OP: you're getting the order of things wrong: you need to "scan" first: copy the old stuff over to the new.  And then you can correct internal references.  Trying to do it the other way around is ineffective due to the constraint of trying to make sure the collector uses a bounded, small amount of auxiliary memory.

Comment: @soegaard: Well in Scheme you have two options by my knowledge: pairs (basicly lists, scheme is a dialect of lisp (list programming)) and vectors. You can also implement a stop and copy garbage collector when your memory is represented as a vector.

Comment: @dyoo: You are right, doing it the other way around would be very stupid, my bad!
And thank you for your time!

Comment: OP: no problem.  I've been revising the answer a bit more to help pinpoint exactly where things can go wrong in the one-pass approach.  Hope the explanation makes sense.  It's one of those things that's really easy to miss.

Comment: Ok, I added historical references to make it easier to see that your question is very natural.  Single-pass is actually how the idea got started, and Cheney developed the two-pass version later to make it much more approachable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are going through the [really awesome garbage collection assignment](http://blog.brownplt.org/2013/02/19/teaching-gc.html) where you implement your own collectors (mark and sweep, stop and copy, generational).

General answer to your question: two-pass algorithms typically use less memory than one-pass algorithms, by trading time for space.

More specific answer: in a stop-and-copy collector, you do it in two passes by (1) first copying the live data over to the new semispace, and (2) adjusting internal references in the live data to refer to elements in the new semispace, mapping old memory to new memory.

You must realize that the information necessary to do the mapping isn't magically available: you need **memory** to **keep track** how to redirect the moved memory.  And remember: your collector itself is a program, and it must use a **bounded, small** amount of memory!  Keeping a hash table in your collector to do the bookkeeping, for example, would be verboten: it's not playing by the rules.  So one thing you need to keep track of is making sure the collector is playing with a limited amount of memory.  So that explains why a stop-and-copy collector will reuse the old semispace and write those redirect records there.

With that constraint in mind: it's important to realize that we need to be careful of how we're traversing the live set.  Which approach we choose may or may not require additional memory, in some very subtle and surprising ways.  In particular, recursion in the general case is not free!  Technically, in the first pass we should be using the **new** semispace not only as the target of our copying, but as a funky representation of the **control** stack that we use to implement the recursive process that walks through the live data.

Concretely, if we're doing a one-pass approach like this to copy the live set:

```
;; copy-live-set: number -> void
;; copies the live set starting from memory-location.

Pseudocode:

to copy-live-set starting at memory-location:

  copy the block at memory-location over to the new semispace, and

  record a redirection record in the old semispace

  for each internal-reference in the block:

      recursively call copy-live-set at the internal-reference if
      it hasn't been copied already

      remap the internal-reference to that new memory location
```

then you may be surprised to know that we've messed up with memory.  The above will break the promise that the collector is making to the runtime environment because the recursion here is not iterative!  It will consume control stack space.  During the live set traversal, it will consume control stack space proportional to the depth of the structures we're walking across.  Ooops.

If you try an alternative approach for walking through the live set, you should eventually see that there's a good way to traverse the whole live set while still guaranteeing bounded, small control stack usage.  Hint: consider how graph traversal algorithms can be written as a simple while loop, with an explicit container that holds what to visit next till we exhaust the container.  If you squint just right, the intermediate values in the new semispace look awfully like that container.

Once you discover how to traverse the live set in constant control stack space, you'll see that you'll need those two passes to do the complete copy-and-rewrite-internal-references thing.  Worrying about these details is messy, but it's important in seeing how garbage collectors actually work.  A real collector needs to do something like this, to be concerned about control stack usage, to ensure it uses bounded memory during the collection.

Summary: a two-pass algorithm is a solution that helps us with memory at the cost of some time.  But we don't pay much in terms of performance: though we pass through the live set twice, the process is still linear in the size of the live set.

---

History: see [Cheney's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm), and note the title of the seminal paper's emphasis: "[A **Nonrecursive** List Compacting Algorithm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362798)". That single highlighted word "Nonrecursive" is the key to what motivates the two-pass approach: it's trying to avoid consuming the control stack.  Cheney's paper is an extension of the paper by Fenichel and Yochelson "[A LISP Garbage-Collector for Virtual-Memory Computer Systems](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/690M/p611-fenichel.pdf)", in which the authors there proposed basically the recursive, stack-using approach first.  To improve the situation, Fenichel and Yochelson then proposed using the non-recursive (but complicated!) [Schorr-Waite DFS algorithm](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2007fa/lectures/lec21-schorr-waite.pdf) to do the traversal.  Cheney's approach is an improvement because the traversal is simpler.